# Physical memory warning

Tags: php, memory, warnings, hosting, shared-hosting

```
<?php
file_put_contents("10gb.zip", fopen("http://website.website/10GB.zip", 'r'));
echo "File Downloaded!";
```

I am using this code to download files from url to my server. But when I run my code My hosing servers memory turn into red! -_- and my download stuck at 3.79 GB.

 Is there any limitation to download big files? i want to download more than 50 GB with 5 process! Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, PHP will try to load the entire file memory.  You need to split the files and process them

Comment: A suggestion, You can use the FTP to download the file, if you have control over the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would go for streaming when dealing with large file rather than copying them directly

from the example provided here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php

you can try :

```
<?php   
    function pipe_streams($in, $out)
    {
        while (!feof($in))
            fwrite($out,fread($in,8192));
    }

    pipe_streams("http://website.website/10GB.zip", "10gb.zip");
?>
```

or use `curl` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) :

```
<?php
    $url  = "http://website.website/10GB.zip";
    $path = "10gb.zip";

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

check this https://www.sitepoint.com/performant-reading-big-files-php/ for more streaming options

Comment: this script not downloading more than 4.69 GB in my server >.<

Comment: disque space ? interrupted connexion maybe ? look for `fwrite` , `pipe_streams` and `curl` to see how to display errors and handle them, check this : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/changing-php-memory-limits